# Compare parameters of multidimentional arrays and merge them

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 multidimensional arrays (`$sorted`, `$sorted_Rcv`), with the parameters `Account`, `Analyzed`, `Received`, `Year` and `Month`. `Received` and `Analyzed` are in different arrays as you can see in the following picture.

[image: Arrays]

What I'm trying to achieve, is to compare the 2 arrays and if `Account`, `Month` and `Year` are identical, merge them, so that in one object I get `Account`, `Received`, `Analyzed`, `Month` and `Year`.

This is my current approach. Where I get the following error:  `Trying to access array offset on value of type int` on the if function.

```
$merged_result = array();
foreach ($sorted as $sorted) {
    foreach ($sorted as $value1) {
      foreach ($sorted_Rcv as $sorted_Rcv) {
            foreach ($sorted_Rcv as $value2) {
                if ($value1['Month'] == $value2['Month'] && $value1['Year'] == $value2['Year']) {
                    $merged_result[]= ['Account' => $value1['Account'], 'Received' => $value2['Received'],'Analyzed' => $value1['Analyzed'],'Month' => $value1['Month'],'Year' => $value1['Year']];
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

Any kind of help is much appreciated!

Comment: another way you can use collection `flatMap` for both array. And merge them together, and then group by `Account Year Month`, at last `flatMap` them to flat each array in group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use next `foreach` loop:

```
$merged_result = array(); 

foreach($sorted as $subar1){
foreach($subar1 as $val){
    foreach($sorted_Rcv as $subar2){ 
    foreach($subar2  as $val2){
        if ($val['Year'] == $val2['Year'] && $val['Month'] == $val2['Month'] && $val['Account'] == $val2['Account']){
            $merged_result[] = [
                                'Year' => $val2['Year'],
                                'Month' => $val2['Month'],
                                'Account' => $val2['Account'],
                                'Analyzed' => $val['Analyzed'],
                                'Received' => $val2['Received'],
            ];
        }   
    }
    }
}
}
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/ZGGYI)**